# Is there a simple text file based database to hold account information for basic node.js/Passport authentication?

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js

I have a Node.js web server running on an embedded Linux system.  For authentication I'm currently using Passport's Local Strategy, and the user account information is stored in the Node script itself as follows.

```
var users = [
    { id: 1, username: 'bob', password: 'secret', email: 'bob@example.com' }
  , { id: 2, username: 'joe', password: 'birthday', email: 'joe@example.com' }
];
```

It works, but I'd like to store the usernames and passwords in a separate file and be able to add, delete and change users through the web browser interface.  I don't want to use a database server to store the user accounts because I feel it's too much overhead for my embedded system.

Does anyone know of a good way to store the user accounts in a separate file with possibly a library to help update the accounts?

**EDIT:**  The Node server is running on electronics hardware which will have very few (2-20 maybe) users, so there shouldn't be a problem with people stepping on each other doing user list updates.  After initial set-up, the user list won't change much.

Comment: First off I would change the password storage. Don't store the actual password, just a hash of it if possible. Right now it's a security risk.

Comment: `bcrypt` is the safest (currently) and very easy to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simple approach would be to just read from a JSON file.  On updates then write to `accounts.json.(process id).tmp` and rename the file to `accounts.json`.  There's a small risk you'll lose an update if two come in at the same time, but maybe you can live with that.  (If you can't then use a "real" database for some value of "real").

You can use `JSON.stringify(data)` to convert a data structure to JSON and `JSON.parse(json)` to convert the JSON string from the file to a data structure.

If your service/server has little enough use that you can block you can read the accounts with

```
var data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync( file_name ) );
```

Answer (score 4):

You're probably already aware that storing passwords in plaintext is a bad idea; at minimum, I would recommend hashing with [bcrypt](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node.bcrypt.js/). However, that's not what the question's about, so we'll move on. :)

You have a few options:

1. Read and save the data to disk manually, using `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`. Load up the data into memory, and when it gets changed, serialize it back to disk.
2. Use [Persistance](https://github.com/creationix/node-persistence), a Node module that supports in-memory storage and automatically persists to disk for you (basically the same as #1 but already built. :)
3. Use [SQLite](https://github.com/developmentseed/node-sqlite3), which gives you most of the features of an RDBS but serializes to a file instead of requiring a running server.

Comment: There I fixed it: `{ id: 1, username: 'bob', password: bcrypt('secret'), email: 'bob@example.com' }`

Answer (score 0):

I am totally unaware of all the three tags used by you, but I got attracted by your question wherein you are asking about a simple text file based database. Please don't mind if you find my answer irrelevant as I am from a totally different background.

Have a look at MongoDB. It is a document-oriented DBMS which is very useful when dealing with large no of documents.

MongoDB uses BSON, a binary object format similar to, but more expressive than, JSON.It is a NOSQL database that stores structured data in BSON format with dynamic schemas instead of storing data in tables as is done in a "classical" RDBMS.

If you find it appealing you can visit this link for more detail : [MongoDb](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Introduction)